# Testing that something fails to parse in Xtext

Tags: xtext

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar ru.focusmedia.fire.idl.IDL with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate idl "http://www.focusmedia.ru/fire/idl/IDL"

Model:
    'package' package=QualifiedName
    imports+=Import*
    typeDefs+=TypeDef+;

...
```

So the string `asd` should fail to parse, as should anything not starting with `package`. I expected `ParseHelper.parse("asd")` to throw an exception or to return `null`, but it does neither. How do I recognize that parsing failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the resource that contains the parse result for errors by means of Resource#getErrors. Something like `resultFromParseHelper.eResource().getErrors()` should do the trick.

Using junit:

```
Assert.assertEquals(result.eResource().getErrors().toString,0,result.eResource().getErrors().size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `ValidationTestHelper`.